# draggable="true" is not working in firefox for Lightning Component

Tags: javascript, lightning, html5

`draggable="true"` is not working in firefox. The following code working fine in chrome,but not in firefox.
**DragDropDemo.app**

```
<aura:application >
    <aura:attribute name="values"
                    type="String[]"
                    access="private" />
    <aura:attribute name="dragid"
                    type="Integer"
                    access="private" />
    <aura:handler name="init"
                  value="{!this}"
                  action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <div class="droparea" 
         ondragover="{!c.cancel}" 
         ondragenter="{!c.cancel}"
         ondrop="{!c.drop}">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.values}"
                        indexVar="index"
                        var="value">
            <div class="row" 
                 draggable="true"
                 ondragstart="{!c.dragstart}"
                 data-drag-id="{!index}">
                {!value}
            </div>
        </aura:iteration>
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

**DragDropDemo.css**

```
.THIS.droparea{
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    margin: 3px;
}
.THIS.droparea .row {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 3px;
}
```

**DragDropDemoController.js**

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        var values = "a b c d e".split(' ');
        component.set("v.values", values);
    },
    dragstart: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.dragid", event.target.dataset.dragId);
    },
    drop: function(component, event, helper) {
        var dragId = component.get("v.dragid"),
            values = component.get("v.values"),
            temp;
        temp = values[dragId];
        values[dragId] = values[event.target.dataset.dragId];
        values[event.target.dataset.dragId] = temp;
        component.set("v.values", values);
        event.preventDefault();
    },
    cancel: function(component, event, helper) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per this [blog post](http://mereskin.github.io/dnd/) "*To make an element draggable set draggable attribute to "true". However this is not enough to make elements draggable in **Firefox**. You need to locate the dragstart event and set some data on the DataTransfer object:*"

```
draggableElement.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e){
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text', 'foo');
});
```

> In your controller you can add `event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', component.id);` and it will start working in Firefox

```
............
    dragstart: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.dragid", event.target.dataset.dragId);
        event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', component.id);
    },
............
```